# Display specific flastlist items with specific keys

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

my data :

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: "1",
    from: "Canada",
    name: "person1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    from: "Canada",
    name: "person2",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    from: "France",
    name: "person3",
  }];
```

i need to filter this flatList and only display people from Canada

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
const result = DATA.filter(element=> element.from === "Canada")
```

Then you can use your result to display it in the format that you want.